# feasible region

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, asymptote

I want to plot the feasible region. But I don't know how. I need guidance.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-1,-3) grid (5,4);
        \draw[very thick,->] (-1,0) -- (5.2,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
        \draw[very thick,->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$x_2$};
        
        \foreach \x in {-1,...,5} \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) node[below] {\tiny\x};
        \foreach \y in {-3,...,4} \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) node[right] {\tiny\y};
        
    
        
        \draw (-1,-3) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$x_1=-1$} (-1,3);
        
        \draw (0,0) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$x_1\leq x_2$} (3,3);
        \draw (0,0) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$x_1\leq x_2$} (3,-3);
        \draw (-1,3) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$x_2=3$} (3,3);
        \draw (-1,3) -- node[above,sloped] {\tiny$x_2=-3$} (3,3);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Current result:

[image: result]

Comment: What are your efforts? You can use https://www.mathcha.io/editor

Comment: @sebastiano This is my code

Comment: What exactly do you want to improve? Do you want to fill the area?

Answer (score 4):

I am unsure how the result should look like exaxtly, but maybe this can help you.

If you want to draw an area, you should connect the lines that represent the border of this area, otherwise what you get is just single lines that are not connected. Also, if the area should not cover parts of the diagram, you should place it before the things that it should not cover:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[gray!50, thin, step=0.5] (-1,-3) grid (5,4);

        \draw[fill=gray!10]
            (-1,-3) 
                -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny$x_1=-1$} (-1,3)
                -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny$x_2=3$} (3,3)
                -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny$x_1\leq x_2$} (0,0)
                -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny$x_1\leq -x_2$} (3,-3)
                -- node[above, sloped] {\tiny$x_2=-3$} cycle;

        \draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (5.2,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$x_2$};
        
        \foreach \x in {-1,...,5} 
            \draw (\x,0.05) -- (\x,-0.05) 
            \ifnum\x=0\relax
                node[below right] {\tiny\x}
            \else
                node[below] {\tiny\x}
            \fi ;
        \foreach \y in {-3,...,4} 
            \draw (-0.05,\y) -- (0.05,\y) 
            \ifnum\y=0\else
                node[right] {\tiny\y}
            \fi ;

        \draw[very thick, <->] 
            (0:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=2] 
            node[midway, right] {\tiny$q$};

        \node[align=center] at (3,-2) {unstable \\ region};
        \node[align=center] at (1,-2) {stable \\ region};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

With most of the labels and the grid removed it resembles more the picture you show:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}

        \draw[fill=gray!10]
            (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (3,3) -- (0,0) -- (3,-3) -- cycle;

        \draw[very thick, ->] (-1,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {$x_1$};
        \draw[very thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {$x_2$};

        \draw[very thick, <->] 
            (0:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=45, radius=2] 
            node[midway, right] {$q$};

        \node[align=center] at (3,-2) {unstable \\ region};
        \node[align=center] at (1,-2) {stable \\ region};
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you think your drawing could be added to tikz.net ?

Comment: @anis Why not. A link to the original answer here can be added, right? I am fine with that.

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht. What should I do if I want the axes to be without numbers  and x1<=x2, x1=-1,....as in the original figure?

Comment: @mzn Just remove these parts from the code ...

Comment: @Jasper Habicht .Thank you very much

Comment: @Jasper Habicht . What should I do to remove the vertical line at the extreme left?

Comment: @mzn Didn't you get an answer for this already to the [other question of yours](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/706918/47927)? I suggest you make yourself familiar with how Ti*k*Z works. This will help you more than me helping you with every single step in your drawing. You can use the [online manual](https://www.tikz.dev) which contains a lot of nice tutorials. You'd need to separately draw the area and the border, for example.

Comment: You can replace `\draw[fill=gray!10] (-1,-3) -- (-1,3) -- (3,3) -- (0,0) -- (3,-3) -- cycle;`  with `\fill[gray!10] (-1,3) -- (3,3) -- (0,0) -- (3,-3) -- (-1,-3) -- cycle; \draw (-1,3) -- (3,3) -- (0,0) -- (3,-3) -- (-1,-3);`. But as I said, better get familiar with the syntax. It is not too difficult to understand, I think.

Comment: @ Jasper Habicht
You are absolutely right. ok sure