# plot stability region

Tags: plot

I want to plot this figure and this is my code and result. I want the vertical line that I marked in the figure to be removed and also the point $q pi/2$ to move away from the arc and not stick to it like original figure.[image] .

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=gray!10]
(-3,-3) -- (-3,3)  -- (0,0) -- cycle;

\draw[very thick, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {Re};
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {Im};

\draw[very thick, <->] 
(0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=135, radius=1] 
node[midway, right] {$q\frac{\pi}{2}$};

\node[align=center] at (2.3,-1) {unstable  region};
\node[align=center] at (-2,-1) {stable  region};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Answer (score 2):

- if you don't want the gray triangle to be closed, then don't close the path with `-- cycle`
- you can shift the node e.g. with `xshift=` and `yshift=`. Alternatively you could increase the `outer sep=` of the node.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[fill=gray!10] (-3,-3)  -- (0,0) -- (-3,3);

\draw[very thick, ->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[right] {Re};
\draw[very thick, ->] (0,-3) -- (0,3.5) node[above] {Im};

\draw[very thick, <->] 
(0:1) arc[start angle=0, end angle=135, radius=1] 
node[midway, right,xshift=0.25cm,yshift=0.25cm] {$q\frac{\pi}{2}$};

\node[align=center] at (2.3,-1) {unstable  region};
\node[align=center] at (-2,-1) {stable  region};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer. And if you want to extend the grey region to the left, you'd need to first draw the area and later add the black lines, such as `\fill[gray!10] (-3.5,-3) -- (-3,-3) -- (0,0) -- (-3,3) -- (-3.5,3) -- cycle; \draw (-3,-3) -- (0,0) -- (-3,3);` instead of `\draw[fill=gray!10] (-3,-3)  -- (0,0) -- (-3,3);`.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thank you